# apply function on two columns in python pandas with 2 arguments (convert GPS type to another)

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, pyproj

so i have a database of X and Y coordinates as the ITM type and i want it as WGS-84 type.
i found a function from pyproj library thats convert and it works great but now i'm having troubles to apply this function on two separate columns.

for example i want to convert this data :

| Column x | Column y |
| --- | --- |
| 643234 | 234562 |
| 634352 | 434534 |

to something like that

| Column X | Column Y |
| --- | --- |
| 33.04647 | 35.56525 |
| 25.34533 | 23.43532 |

so my function accepts two arguments(X from Column x and Y from column y) and needs to replace all the values to the new coordinates data
any one has an idea how to use the apply function to work on both columns

i tried to use apply function on both column but it didn't worked out and i couldn't find a solution online  and i also tried to change my Function to work separately on one column but its impossible because its a built in function of a certain library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1400

```py
from pyproj import Transformer

trans = Transformer.from_crs(
    "epsg:4326",
    "+proj=utm +zone=10 +ellps=WGS84",
    always_xy=True,
)
xx, yy = trans.transform(My_data["LON"].values, My_data["LAT"].values)
My_data["X"] = xx
My_data["Y"] = yy
```